# NULL values in SQL server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a Status column in a table which has 3 values - 'N/A' , 'Single' ,'Multiple'. Some rows have a `NULL` value for the Status column.

I need to pull up all the rows in which Status is not null and is not 'N/A'. Basically, I need all the rows whose status is "Single"  or "Multiple".

I've been just reading up about NULL actually being equivalent to 'UNKNOWN'.

If I say

```
SELECT *
FROM t_userstatus
WHERE status <> 'N/A'
```

I get the results (All rows containing "Single"  or "Multiple" only).

What I would like to know is that , does the above `WHERE` clause always exclude the rows having NULL values?Is that the expected behaviour?

**What causes this to exclude null rows even though I've not explicitly specified it?**

In my query,do I have to explicitly say status `IS NOT NULL` ?

I am relatively new to programming, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL uses [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29): true, false, and unknown.  Any comparison to `null` results in `unknown`.

So `null <> 'N/A'` evaluates to `unknown`.  Since `unknown` is not true, that means the row gets excluded.

Answer (score 6):

It is not normal behavior as `N/A` (`Single` & `Multiple` as well) is a string that is not related to `NULL`. Even though the `NULL` is evaluated to unknown and may not return, you **should** explicitly use `IS NOT NULL`.

```
SELECT [column_list] FROM t_userstatus
WHERE status IS NOT NULL AND status <> 'N/A'
```

I would also recommend you get in the habit of specifying a column list.

Comment: I agree that you should explicitly use is not null for clarity reasons for the next human, however that is normal behavior for the server given default configuration.  I also agree with the habit about specifying a column list under normal circumstances, but there are rare times when * is truly appropriate in ways that a complete column list isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the normal behavior. A `NULL` value has no value, so it does not satisfy a `WHERE` condition.  If you want to also include null values, you need to specify `IS NOT NULL` as well.

Answer (score 2):

A bit non-obviously, SQL has three valued logic (true/false/unknown). Any direct comparison with `NULL` will result in the value `unknown` which in the `WHERE` clause is considered non-true. Your condition;

```
WHERE status <> 'N/A'
```

will in other words never match a null since `NULL` is never "not equal" to anything.

The only ways to match a `NULL` using a comparison is using the special null operations `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

As a side note, [life is naturally never quite that simple.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#SQL)

Comment: A comparison to `null` returns `unknown`, not `false`

Comment: @Andomar From a three value logic perspective, that makes sense.  For the internals of SQL Server, the documentation indicates it really is false.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229(v=sql.80).aspx see second paragraph under remarks.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman - The documentation is wrong then. Probably no one has bothered correcting it as it is for SQL Server 2000. [Updated version of that article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx). If it evaluated to `false` then `NOT (status <> 'N/A')` would be true. It isn't. Also a check constraint with `NULL <> 'N/A'` would not allow any rows to be inserted. It does.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, null is generally not comparable.  So, a status != 'N/A' comes back as false when status is null.

But what others haven't mentioned yet is that that is controlled through the Ansi_nulls setting.  By default it is on and nulls are not comparable (as you state in the question, the principal behind this is that they are unknown so it is false that they are not necessarily N/A).  But you can use

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

To change this behavior in which case a null will be equal to a null and not equal to anything else.  There is more details on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).