# If I have a query that compares two dates in SQL Server, what will happen if one of the dates is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a query that has a WHERE clause like:

```
where date1 > date2
```

What will happen if date2 is null? Do I need to specify that date1 and date2 both be not null?

The types are DATE()

Comment: More info on the NULLs behavior here : http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~wlam/compsci/sqlnulls. By the way, you could exclude date1 / date2 where the value is NULL from your request

Comment: possible duplicate of [NULL values in SQL server query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201940/null-values-in-sql-server-query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will try to compare `date1` to `NULL` and it will evaluate to unknown.

```
WHERE '2013-07-18' > NULL
```

is *unknown*. See my blog post on [`NULL` behavior in 3 valued logic](http://www.jadito.us/2013/01/07/null-behavior-for-three-valued-logic).

You will want to use a function like `ISNULL` around `date2` or explicitly write out the logic. Using `ISNULL` will prevent an index from being used, however. You could write:

```
WHERE (date1 > date2 OR date2 IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

always UNKNOWN. NULL value must be treated with IS NULL statement

Try this example:

```
    declare @d1 datetime
    declare @d2 datetime
    set @d1 = GETDATE()

    select 
    case
        when @d1 > @d2 then 'OK'
        else 'KO'
    end
```

Comment: Slightly nitpicky but the comparison isn't false. It's NULL (which can be thought of as unknown). In this example there's no difference because it's not true but it can bite you if you assume x=NULL is false

Comment: Correct (false -> unknown). ;)

Answer (score 1):

Any value, when compared for equality to `NULL`, will yield a value of `False`, even when comparing `NULL` to `NULL`.

You can use the `IS NULL` operator to check values for `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Either use an ISNULL on the nullable date and replace it with a default date or other field.

For instance:

Where Date1 > ISNULL(date2, '1900-01-01').

Better yet, replace the hardcode with a default parameter.

Declare @defaultvardt DATE = '1900-01-01'

Where Date1 > ISNULL(date2, @defaultvardt)